# Using SystemSoundID in UIViewController without Application Delegate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an experimental app for iPad with a UIViewController visible on launch connected to my AppDelegate... all good, when I use systemSoundID within this MainViewcontroller it works great however when I try to use systemSoundID in my 3 other ViewController classes, which are connected to my MainViewController but not to AppDelegate they don't work???

I dont understand the significance of the AppDelegate here??

Is there a way to make SystemSoundID work in my other ViewController classes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported audiotoolbox header files in other 3 viewControllers. Try to import header files in other view controllers and then play systemSound.

Comment: Yes, I have the  audiotoolbox header in the .h of all of my viewcontrollers. I made 2 projects to test this and it is the same in both.